# Combining the logs from multiple directories in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have log files going into different directories based on the date created of the log file.

For example

```
> /mypath/2017/01/20/... 
.
.
.
> /mypath/2017/02/13/...
> /mypath/2017/02/14/...
```

I would like to combine all these log files into one single rdd using pyspark so that I can do the aggregates on this master file.

Till date, I have taken individual directories, called sqlContext and used Union to join all the log file for specific dates.

```
DF1 = (sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("/mypath/2017/02/13")).union(sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("/mypath/2017/02/14"))
```

Is there an easy way to get the master rdd by specifying the log files from range of dates? (i.e from 2017/01/20 to 2017/02/14)

I am quite new to spark, please correct me if I was wrong at any step.

Comment: Also, If I want to filter based on a column "Type" after I join all these logs(say DF1). What would be the optimal process to do so? (I usually use DF1.filter()). Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("/mypath/2017/02/[13-14]‌​")) is not working. It says "Illegal file pattern: Illegal character range near index 4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick with the sqlContext then a easy solution it will be to define a method that will list all your files within the input directory

```
case class FileWithDate(basePath: String, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
 def path = s"${basePath}/${year}/${month}/${day}"
}

def listFileSources() : List[FileWithDate] = ??? // implement here
```

If you want to union all dataframes from the sources you can do it like this:

```
// create an empty dataframe with the strucutre for the json
val files = listSources()
val allDFs = files.foldLeft(emptyDF){case (df, f) => df.union(sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(f.path))}
```

If you want to filter the input files by date, then it will be easy. Something like this

```
files.filter(_.year == 2016 && (_.month >=2 || _.month <=3))
```

Another solution it will be to augment your dataframes(put additional columns) with year, month, day and do all the business logic on new dataframes

Comment: I think that with minimum Scala knowledge you will be able to to implement listFileSources method. What you should do there is to get all files within the mypath folder (recursive iterate over sub-folder) and create objects of type FileWithDate. Those object are appended to a list that will be returned by the method.